# How to programatically get the line number for large files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there some way to get the line number for >50 MB large files and the content of this line?

In a large file, I can't get an instance of `activeTextEditor`:

```
const activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
```

It is strange for me, as a user I see the line number, but I can't read it programmatically... :-/

This behaviour makes VS Code Extensions not usable for me on larger projects. :-(

Comment: Are you creating a VS Code extension? Or are you simply just using VS Code as an editor? Because you tagged this with [tag:visual-studio-code] but it's not clear whether this is for an extension or you are creating a program that reads large files. Please also tag with the language.

Comment: Hello Gino, I'm creating a VS Code Extension... This extension uses VS Code API for accessing activeTextEditor.  Thank you for your reply. I added tag "vscode-extensions".

Comment: you can't open files >50MB with the API, maybe they have also excluded the extension API to files >50MB

Comment: rioV8, thank you for your reply. Hmm, that's a pity...

I will solve this issue by user dialog with prompt for copy active line number. It will be crazy "user interactive", but working...